# Code Signing issue after adding another project XCode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate, code-signing-entitlements

I have addd Chart project in my current project. It working fine in simulator. But when i build the project as distribution certificate it will create issue.

```
Code Sign error: Multiple matching codesigning identities found: Multiple codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs).
```

but i have used already created certificate and ID in both project

Comment: You must set Team and Certificate same for both. Provisioning profile can be different but under same certificate.

Comment: @Poles: Ya i have already set as per your suggestion

Comment: Clean the project and build again.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the below steps

1. Refresh your provisioning profile

[image]

[image]

2. Check your keychain

   Delete the duplicate certificates, if any.

Comment: i checked this way but there is no duplicate certificate. thanks for suggestion